# Space between lines gets added when I change the font size

Tags: spacing, fontsize

Iʻm making a summary of an Algebra class. For the Derivation of the quadratic formula,  I have the following code:

```
\huge
\begin{center}
Derivation of the Quadratic Formula
\end{center}
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:1}
\Large
\begin{align}
0&=ax^{2}+bx+c\\
0&=a\left( x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\right)+c\\
0&=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)+\frac{c}{1}-\frac{ab^2}{4a^2}\\
0&=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\\
\frac{-4ac+b^2}{4a}&=a\left (x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\frac{-4ac+b^2}{4a^2}&=\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt{-4ac+b^2}}{2a}&=x+\frac{b}{2a}\\
\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{-4ac+b^2}}{2a}&=x\\
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&=x
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
Note: Completing the square can be found in steps a through d.
\pagebreak
```

For some reason, changing the font size to `\Large` from `\huge` adds a weird space between the title and the math. Do you know what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Are you sure you want to change the font size (and work with `center` in the way you do)?

Comment: Can you please make your code snippet compilable? Then we have not to guess which class and packages you are using ...

Comment: Are you referring to [this gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBeXZ.png)?

Comment: Use `\centering` instead of | `\begin{center] \end{center}`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is a result of the fact that, by default, `amsmath` environments do not allow page breaking: When you change `\Large` to `\huge` the equations are now too large to fit on the same page as the title, so `amsmath` starts a new page. To get around this, there are two main options:

- Add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to your preamble, which tells the `amsmath` package it should insert a page break where appropriate
- (for finer control), add `\displaybreak` before the `\\` on the line you think a page break should ideally follow

Example preamble for the first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
```

and example usage of the second:

```
\huge
\begin{align}
0&=ax^{2}+bx+c\\
0&=a\left( x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\right)+c\\
0&=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)+\frac{c}{1}-\frac{ab^2}{4a^2}\\
0&=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\\
\frac{-4ac+b^2}{4a}&=a\left (x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\frac{-4ac+b^2}{4a^2}&=\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt{-4ac+b^2}}{2a}&=x+\frac{b}{2a}\displaybreak\\ % Put a page break here, please
\frac{-b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{-4ac+b^2}}{2a}&=x\\
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}&=x
\end{align}
```